# Why my discord.py slash commands doesn't appears on DIscord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make slash commands on Discord using discord.py, but it doesn't appears on my Discord.

I tried to change to "tree.command()" instead of "bot.tree.command" but it doesn't work.

```
import discord, os, json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

with open("parameters.json") as par:
    data = json.load(par)
print(f"JSON file loaded with this data:\n{data}")

token = data["token"]
prefix = data["prefix"]
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= prefix,intents=discord.Intents.all())
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("\nBot is ready")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Sincronized {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
#COMMANDS
@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    latency = format(round(bot.latency, 1))
    await ctx.send(f'Pong!\nCurrent latency: {latency}ms')
#SLASH COMMANDS
@bot.tree.command(name="ping")
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Pong")
#EVENTS

#RUN
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to add ```await tree.sync()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you wait a bit? It can take up to an hour for global slash commands to show up. If you do not want to wait (in development for example), you can sync the slash commands to one guild, then they show up instantly. For example:

```py
await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(1234567)) # Replace with your Guild ID
```

Also generally it is regarded as bad practice to sync your commands (or do any API calls at all for that matter) in the `on_ready` event as it will fire multiple times.
You could look into syncing your commands in the `setup_hook` ([here is the official example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py) on slash commands on how to do it), or write a command that syncs your slash commands, something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sync(ctx: commands.Context, guild: discord.Guild = None) -> None:
    if guild is None:
        await bot.tree.sync()
    else:
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
```

You would need to run this command every time you change your commands though.